# Tool for stylecop exclude files

Tags: c#, stylecop

I'm working on a legacy product and need to bring in stylecop to development. As per the guidelines on the stylecop documentation for legacy projects, I want to exclude all the existing files so that only new files will be checked for stylecop. Does anybody know any tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Manually or via some `PowerShell` script  add following on the top of each file in the old project:

```
// <auto-generated>
```